# Entity Framework 4 Change Audit

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a web application using EF4. I am somewhat new to EF and now trying to implement change Audit.I tried to do this by trapping the SavingChanges event of the Context Class as below

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
        {
            this.SavingChanges += new EventHandler(TicketContainer_SavingChanges);

        }
```

So the event handler accesses the changed records by the following

```
this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
             EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified);
```

This works fine and I am creating column level audit for selected tables. Every table/entity has an ID field which is an identifier with columnName="ID". So in my audit routine I simply accesses data from column with name "Id" to get the ID of audited record.

The problem I face is during insert . The new record has no ID yet as it is an identity column in the database and is always 0.

One solution I can think of is using GUID for all Ids.But is there a way to implement this using standard int32 Identity Ids?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we insert data through EF the identity column is not generted while insertion. To get the Id of Identity columns we have to insert the data first then only we can get the Id of coulmn.

please go through the below which might be helpful to you.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplAudingTrailUsingEFP1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't now how many entities you have but in our own implementation of audit tracking we created a specific audit entity for each entity so we could link them together trough navigational properties and let the database set the identity keys.

If you use inheritance for your audit entities it's quit easy to query them.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Wouter Thanks for answering.I did not fully understand what you suggested.But probably you are creating a Fkey from Audit table to your actual table as you have 1 audit table for each entity.But in my case I have only a single audit table across all entities

Comment: Why is that you are limited to one table? If you use TablePerHierarchy inheritance you could still put your whole inheritance hierarchy in on table. You would for example have a PersonAudit type with a TargetPerson property and a TargetPersonId (FK) and a OrderAudit with a property TargetOrder and a TargetOrderId

Answer (score 0):

Identity columns are not generated while insertion. Once data is inserted then only you can get identity column data in EF. So, you can try some work around by getting Id after insertion and then populating audit table with that Id.